# How to get the Image from a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiimageview, uiimage, xcode4.5

I am new in iOS application Development. I need help on UIImageView. I need to send an Image to the server which the user will sketch. In my application i am using UIImageView on which user can sketch and fill colors etc its like a pain application. now i need to send that sketch to server as user will click on UPDATE button. for sending the data through web service, i have to send it as a binary string i think. every thing is working fine and clear to me. The problem is how to get the image from UIImageView with out saving it to core data or sq-lite as i don't want to save that image permanently.

Is it Possible to get UIImage from an UIImageView without using core data or sq-lite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to Get      `UIImage` for `UIImageView` then try this.

`UIImageView *imageView = ... //here is your UIImageView.`

`UIImage *image = imageView.image; //Here is you UIImage`

if any issue please let me know.

Comment: thank you i got the solution now i trapped on one more thing       NSString *imgstr=[imgdata base64Encoding];   this base64Encoding is not supported by ios6 ithink so any alternate for that

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your question completely.

For getting image from `UIImageView`

```
UIImage *image = imageView.image;
```